# How will you write this code from Android to iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I am trying to learn how to port android apps to iOS for education reasons.I believe I have the solution to this code, but I want to make sure I get this right.

Here is the Android code (java) that I am trying to port to iOS(objective c).

```
  this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
    setBoldFont();
```

This is what I believe the answer is, but I am not too familiar with Java programming.

```
   UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
  image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
```

Comment: So what do you believe the answer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to set the background image of View try this.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
```

If you don't want to set backgroundColor and use UIImage, addChild UIImaveView in UIView and set its image property.